# STI in Rails: How do I change from a superclass to a subclass without accessing the "type" attribute directly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti

So, I have the following:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Has a bunch of common stuff about assembly hierarchy, etc
end

class SpecializedProduct < Product
  # Has some special stuff that a "Product" can not do!
end
```

There's a manufacturing and assembly process in which data is captured about Products. At the time of capture the eventual product type is not known. after the Product record has been created in the database (perhaps days later) it may be necessary to turn that product into a specialized product and fill in the additional information. Not all products will become specialized, however.

I've been trying to use the following:

```
object_to_change = Product.find(params[:id])
object_to_change.becomes SpecializedProduct
object_to_change.save
```

Then, when I do a `SpecializedProduct.all` the resulting set does not include `object_to_change`. Instead `object_to_change` is still listed in the database as `Product`

```
UPDATE "products" SET "type" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "products"."type" IN ('SpecializedProduct') AND "products"."id" = 30  [["type", "Product"], ["updated_at", Fri, 17 May 2013 10:28:06 UTC +00:00]]
```

So, after the call to `.becomes SpecializedProduct` the `.save` method is now using the right type, but it's not able to update the record because the `WHERE` clause of the update is too specific.

Do I really need to access the `type` attribute of the model directly? I'd really rather not.

Comment: short answer: yes, you need to update it with type. In general, STI is not designed to change classes over time.

Answer (score 3):

You just need the bang version of the becomes method with (!) and save.

The difference between the two methods: `becomes` creates a new instance of the new class with all the same attribute values of the original object.  `becomes!` also updates the type column.

```
object_to_change = Product.find(params[:id])
object_to_change.becomes! SpecializedProduct
object_to_change.save
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source of `becomes` and `becomes!`, it doesn't mutate the original object. You need to assign it to a new variable:

```
some_product = Product.find(params[:id])
specialized_product = some_product.becomes SpecializedProduct
specialized_product.save
```

Not sure how this will handle the primary key of the record, though, so you may need to do some additional finagling to make sure your relations don't get mangled.

Answer (score 0):

I think no! Check the sorces of `becomes` and `becomes!` methods!
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L199

Looks like you need to use `becomes!` because it is wrapper around `becomes` that also changes the instance's sti column value.

**UPD:**  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/test/cases/persistence_test.rb#L279 
This is a test case for your code.

**UPD2:** 
I think you can try to create another class sort of DefaultProject which is subclass of Project and then you can change each from DefaultProject to SpecializedProduct  and vice versa

Comment: I get the same resulting SQL on the rails console with `.becomes!` as I do with `.becomes` `SET "type" = ?` is still in there, but unfortunately so is `"products"."type" IN ('SpecializedProduct')` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: see my updated answer, it should work...what rails version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue where I want to change from one subclass to another.  Unfortunately Rails doesn't do this gracefully because it wants to limit the save with a "where type='NewSubclass'". ie:

```
UPDATE parents SET type='NewSubclass' WHERE type IN 'NewSubclass' AND id=1234
```

Digging into rails, it appears that the method in ActiveRecord's lib/active_record/inheritance.rb named "finder_needs_type_condition?" is called and the caller isn't smart enough to realize you are changing the type field so it obviously isn't already that value.

I "resolved" this in a round about way.  I used the ActiveRecord core as a basis for how to load an instance of whichever class I want with attributes and save it without having to go through the full ActiveRecord find stack.

```
old_instance = Parent.find(id) #returns OldSubclass instance
tmp = Parent.allocate.init_with('attributes' => old_instance.attributes)
tmp.type = 'NewSubclass'
tmp.save
Parent.find(id) #returns NewSubclass instance
```

It's real ugly and I hate it.  Hopefully someone will think about fixing this in ActiveRecord.  I believe it would be useful for objects to change subclasses in STI over time.  I have a single table with 5 subclasses because it cleans up the model quite a bit.

This is the only ugliness I had to live with.  Be sure to write proper tests so that when ActiveRecord breaks this "workaround" you can detect it.